# Loop for grayscale png files in R

Tags: r, file, loops, png

I read png file 28x28px and then I select grayscale:

```
img = readPNG("../Folder/image.png")
pic <- img[,,1]+img[,,2]+img[,,3]
pic <- pic/max(pic)'
result = pic*255
result
```

And now i try make loop for more png files in some folder:

```
img = lapply(sprintf("image%i.png", 1:10), png::readPNG) #select 10 png files
pic <- img[,,1]+img[,,2]+img[,,3]
pic <- pic/max(pic)'
result = pic*255
result
```

But it does not work :(

> Error in img[, , 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply` creates a list of images, so in your case `img[[1]]` is the first image and `img[[10]]` is the 10th image. Try looping through each image in list. So if you wanted to do the do the addition operation on image 1, you'd need to do:

```
pic <- img[[1]][,,1]+img[[1]][,,2]+img[[1]][,,3]
```

To do this over all items in the list.

```
img.list <- lapply(sprintf("../Folder/image%i.png", 1:10), png::readPNG) #select 10 png files
results <- list()
for (img in img.list) {
    pic <- img[,,1]+img[,,2]+img[,,3]
    pic <- pic/max(pic)
    results[[length(results)+1]] <- pic*255
}
```

Now result is a list of results for all images.

Comment: Thank u very much! But I select from  28x28 matrix of png specific 3x3 matrices and i need loop through matrix, not list. when i change code from result = c(result,pic*255) to result=pic*255 then result ist just one matrix, not all 10

Comment: Sorry, should be fixed. Each ith image is now in `results[[i]]`

Comment: Thank u for your help. I appreciate it. I have one question - why result "o" in my code give 10x same matrix, when i have 10 different matrices(10xpng file 28x28px)? 

filenames <- Sys.glob("*.png")
o<-array(0,c(28,28,length(filenames)))
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
  img <-readPNG(filenames)
  pic <-img[,,1]+img[,,2]+img[,,3]
  pic <- pic/max(pic)
  o[,,i] <- pic*255
}